# Select the most occuring value for the last 3 months or the most occuring value for the life time

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The data in the **LifestyleProfile** table looks like this:

| UserId | Month | dailyloadtype |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-06-01 | LATE_EVE |
| 1 | 2023-05-01 | LATE_EVE |
| 1 | 2023-04-01 | LATE_EVE |
| 1 | 2023-03-01 | LATE_EVE |
| 1 | 2023-02-01 | DAY_LOAD |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | DAY_LOAD |
| 2 | 2023-06-01 | LATE_EVE |
| 2 | 2023-05-01 | DAY_LOAD |
| 2 | 2023-04-01 | DAY_LOAD |
| 2 | 2023-03-01 | LATE_EVE |
| 2 | 2023-02-01 | DAY_LOAD |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 | DAY_LOAD |

The expected output is this:

| UserId | dailyloadtype |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | LATE_EVE |
| 2 | DAILY_LOAD |

The logic behind this calculation is that if the user has a same **dailyloadtype** for the last 3 latest months then consider that value, else consider the most occurring **dailyloadtype** value for that user.

Answer (score 2):

Following `Cte` is related to last 3 months Data. `Cte2` is Related to most Occurred data of Users. if last 3 months data is there considering cte `dailyloadtype` else cte2 `dailyloadtype` as follows.

```
declare @lastmonthStart date=DATEADD(M,-1,DATEADD(d,-day(getdate()-1),GETDATE()));
with Cte as(
  select LP.UserId ,LP.dailyloadtype from LifestyleProfile LP where LP.Month>=DATEADD(M,-2,@lastmonthStart) and LP.Month<=@lastmonthStart
  group by LP.UserId ,LP.dailyloadtype
  having COUNT(LP.UserId)=3
),cte2 as(
  select LP.UserId ,LP.dailyloadtype,row_number() over(partition by LP.UserId 
  order by COUNT(LP.UserId) desc ) RwNUm
  from LifestyleProfile LP
  group by LP.UserId ,LP.dailyloadtype
)
  select cte2.UserId,coalesce(cte2.dailyloadtype,cte.dailyloadtype) from cte2 left join Cte on Cte.UserId=cte2.UserId where cte2.RwNUm=1
```

Comment: @Teja Goud Kandula mention need any changes or extra logic

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your date ranges are supposed to work when the next month rolls over, etc. That's a detail that should be easy for you to work out.

```
select UserId, mode(DailyLoadType) as DailyLoadType
from LifestyleProfile
where Month > dateadd(month, -4, currentdate)
group by UserId;
```

If all the values are the same, per user, then `mode()` will return that same value. If there are only two possible values then there can't be a tie with an odd number of rows. Should the handling of ties become necessary then you can modify the question.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/mode